# Why Can't I declare char array in IF-Else?

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement, char, declaration

I am trying to give the size of a Char array inside if-else depending upon the number of lines in the file. But when I try to use it afterwards, it gives error: "array undeclared"

```
FILE *f=fopen("G:\\workspaceC\\small1.txt","r");

while((c=fgetc(f))!=EOF)
{
    if(c=='\n')
        no_of_lines++;
}
printf("no_of_lines:  %d",no_of_lines);
int fclose(FILE *f);

if(no_of_lines<10){
    char b[30];
}
else if(no_of_lines>10 && no_of_lines<15){
    char b[60];
}
else{
    char b[106];
}

 for(z=0;z<size;z++)
    {
        if(c==b[z])  ///////Here it gives error: "b undeclared"
        {
            flag=1;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can — you showed how. The trouble is that the scope of the array is the block in which you declare it. And you can't access the variable outside those blocks. Also, note that you declare `fclose()` — and you shouldn't need to do that because `#include <stdio.h>` does that — rather than call it to close the file.

Comment: `int fclose(FILE *f);` --> `fclose(f);`

Comment: Incidentally, you count the number of lines, and then allocate more or less bytes depending on the number of lines, not how long the lines are.  You may need to think rather carefully about what you're up to.

Answer (score 2):

Array declared within a `if` block will become local within the block. In technical terms its scope is limited to the `if` block only. That is why you get the error. Move the declaration outside the block.

There are more problems though:

1. You read the whole file first to decide the number of lines and throw away all the data you read.
2. Where are you initializing the array contents? You will end up with problems because of that.

Therefore better thing is to use file API to find the file size first, dynamically allocate space for that, read the content into the dynamically allocated space and process the data appropriately.

Comment: To add to this, OP probably needs VLA, dynamic allocation, or better yet - simply declare array of the biggest possible size. 106 bytes is nothing.

Comment: But then how will I assign the size ?

Comment: @user3213918: Why bother? How much memory does your machine have?  More than a megabyte, I bet (probably 4-16 GiB).  So, allocating 4096 bytes for `b` really isn't going to tax your machine very much.  Don't fret the silly stuff.  If you must fret about it, then choose a size conditionally (`int size;`), then `int b[size];` is a VLA — variable length array.  Of course, that assumes your compiler is not more than 15 years out of date (C99 requires VLA support).  If you're stuck in the 25-year time-warp (C89), then you don't have VLAs and you need to use `malloc()` and `free()` instead.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Or alloca?

Answer (score 2):

You have declared the array **b** in the `if` block. So, it is only visible to `if` block. And, it cannot be visible outside the `if` block.

If you change the code as follow, you will achieve what you want.

```
int size;
if(no_of_lines<10){
    size = 30;
}
else if(no_of_lines>10 && no_of_lines<15){
    size = 60;
}
else{
    size = 106;
}
char b[size];
```

Comment: It worked perfect. missed that logic :)

Thanks a lot

Comment: @user3213918 This is very bad solution! According to the standard it should not work (and yes, I know that actually it works in gcc, but it does not mean that it is gonna work in every environment). Array must be initialized with a constant (value, or constant variable)!

Answer (score 1):

`---->` In the `IF-ELSE` statement, allocate memory instead of declaring the array.

1. char *arr
2. `malloc((sizeof(char)*30/60/106)`

Answer (score 0):

You declared your array in a block code {}. Regardless whether this block is in if statement or not, you can access this array only in this block.

If you want to dynamically change the size of the array, declare on a pointer at the beginning of the function and then dynamically allocate memory for it (e.g., using malloc). However, it seems that in you case, you can just declare on the array and give it the maximal size you will need.